# Ruby - undefined method в скоупе класса

Tags: ruby

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с такой проблемой: Имеется класс `Model` и методы класса внутри `class << self`. Но когда пытаюсь достучаться до метода класса `db_name` - получаю ошибку `` undefined local variable or method `db_name' for SimplyRecord::Model:Class ``. Думал, что возможно стоит попробовать исп. другой скоуп, но не помогло. В чем может быть проблема?

```
class Model
  puts "#{self} has been initialized"

  class << self

    STANDART_METHODS = [
        { name: :first, query: "SELECT * FROM #{db_name if db_name} ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1;" },
    ]

    STANDART_METHODS.each do |method|
      define_method(method[:name]) do |arg|
        return if self == Model
        arg ||= nil
        data = client.query(method[:query])
        data.to_a.inject([]) do |arr, o|
          new_obj = self.new
          o.each { |k, v| new_obj.instance_variable_set(:"@#{k}", v) }
          arr << new_obj
        end
      end
    end

    def db_name
      self.to_s.underscore.pluralize
    end

    private

    def client
      SimplyRecord::Connection.new.set
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: это вы сами написали или откуда-то скопировали?

Comment: Сам писал. Только сейчас догадался, что сперва нужно, чтобы метод инициализировался, а только потом его нужно вызывать

Comment: вы явно перемудрили тут. попробуйте написать проще. но еще лучше попробуйте начать с тестов.

Comment: Ну да, у вас в интерполяции `db_name if db_name` вызывает то, чего ещё нет. А ещё это избыточный код, поведение которого будет отличаться от просто `db_name` лишь в том случае, если там будет `false`, что для суффикса `_name` было бы очень странно.